# Trying to learn the D programming language, where can I get involved in a project or where should I start?

Tags: open-source, programming-languages, d

So I've been reading up on the D programming language for a while, and it really seems like a cool new language to learn.  My impression is that it combines the power of C with intuitive syntax and garbage collection.  What more could I want?  Ok...so these accounts I've been reading are probably a bit idealized.

However, I just downloaded a D compiler and am looking to learn.  I feel like a great way to learn might be to just get hands on in a project.  I have no idea where to start though.  Where could I find some easy, small D projects (that might actually contribute something to the world)?  Or if not getting hands on in something, how would you recommend learning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about a quick tutorial,

please check the following link:

http://www.dprogramming.com/tutorial.php